# Owl carousel conflict on pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel, pagination

I have mapped a sample data with images that will be appended dynamically into the page. However there's a problem when I'm using the *easypaginate.js*, it paginates but then the carousel doesn't work. Just wanted to achieve a simple pagination with an owl carousel per item, but the owl carousel stops working after initializing the paginate script. Try to remove the easypaginate initialization in the script.

```
$('#container').easyPaginate({
    paginateElement: 'div.contentWrapper',
    elementsPerPage: 2,
    effect: 'default'
});
```

Here's a [demo](https://codepen.io/ehnoxx07/pen/RZqMyg)

Comment: It could be because of jquery conflict. Refer to these - https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/  , https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/